# What all does the sandbox attribute restrict in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, sandbox

I've been thinking about using an iframe to run HTML code (with CSS and JavaScript). I knew that JavaScript can't be unsafe to run, and so I was told to look into the `sandbox` attribute. I've been looking things up for quite a while, and nothing really says what all the `sandbox` attribute actually does. The closest thing was [this article](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/iframe-sandbox-tutorial) from Google Cloud, but that still doesn't say a ton.

MDN, W3Schools, and other documentation websites say that it adds restrictions to enhance security, but I want to understand a little more about what restrictions are added. And do these restrictions make it safe to run JavaScript code? I would need to include `allow-scripts` for an `<iframe>` to run JavaScript code anyways, right?

---

I am wanting to use this for a programming help website. The `<iframe>` will be used to run HTML code (with CSS and hopefully eventually JavaScript) that the users write. Because this is for the Senior Project for my Bachelor's degree, I don't *need* it to run JavaScript as well, but it would be a plus.

A clarification question. If I were just to allow the users to run HTML with CSS, I could add the `sandbox` attribute, and would be fine, correct? Because `sandbox` without `allow-scripts` would block scripts from running, right?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox is pretty detailed in all the possible values you can specify, and what it does when you don't specify anything? By default it allows "none of the things in the list", and setting `allow-...` values will override corresponding restriction.

Comment: So it is just those things in the list? Nothing more?

Comment: If that is the case, then I still would not want to allow JavaScript from running, right?

Comment: Before anyone can answer that, you'll have to explain what you're putting in your iframe =) If it's your own content then there's very little reason to sandbox - if it's another site, then yeah you want to allow scripts because the modern web kind of needs them to work at all (for the majority of sites). If it's something else: remember to talk about that in your post.

Comment: Oh, yeah. I forgot to mention what I would be loading in the `<iframe>`, I will edit my answer and include that. Thank you for reminding me.

Comment: If you're running user generated code in an iframe you _really_ want to run that on a different domain so that the content runs with different-origin rules by default (and then use `sandbox` with specific allow rules to further tailor what you need based on the type of content you're letting your users create).

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help! That makes sense. Hopefully my idea for how to make that work, will actually work... so, we'll see. Thank you, again.

Comment: One last thing. I am wanting to allow them to edit and run the code right there, not just run what has been saved, what are your thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: either postMessage or websockets, it's a big topic, worth searching how other folks tackled that problem first.